# Не загружается файл на сервер!

Tags: php, yii2

На форме есть `<input type="file">`. Форма имеет атрибут `enctype="multipart/form-data"` и `method="post"`. Файл выбран небольшой (меньше 1 мб). На сервере в полученном запросе массив `$_FILES` пуст. В чем может быть проблема? Раньше работало нормально.

Comment: Для начала откройте мониторинг сети в инструментах разработчика в браузере и посмотрите, отправляется ли файл вообще

Comment: У input нет атрибута name, сабмит формы перехватывается js'ом и он творит, что хочет, опечатка где-нибудь.

Comment: @andreymal разве это там отображается? Или мне надо смотреть по хедерам вроде `Content-Length`?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин есть там name. Просто я его не указал в вопросе.

Comment: Нашел одну странность в devtools браузера: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. Это несмотря на то что в форме на 200% указано `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Не понимаю как это происходит, но тип меняется при отправке походу.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК js наврено сабмитит форму. Есть js на странице? Попробуйте без него. В девтулах в испекторе можно увидеть обработчики событий.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин обычный ActiveForm из Yii. Не знаю точно как там он работает, но вроде он должен только валидировать и все. Никогда с ним с отправкой файлов проблем не было. Я не могу просто перестать его использовать, т.к. он повсеместно используется. Не может быть чтобы в нем была проблема.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК добавьте в вопрос про ActiveForm и приложите пример кода, который строит форму. Думаю дело в том, что вы неправильно его используете. Как вы добавили файл в форму? Через `$form->field` или вручную?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин `$form->field` конечно.

Comment: Не знаю важно ли это, но на этой форме на самом деле очень много полей и помимо файловых. Все отправляется одним запросом. Вообще форма очень большая.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается у одного из полей на форме была `enableAjaxValidation` аяксовая валидация. Поэтому запросы шли без файлов - только на валидацию той модели. А уже потом основной с файлами и остальными полями. Но до основного не доходило, т.к. аяксовый запрос никак отдельно не обрабатывался. Теперь все ок!